# Dynamic UI/Server Modules in Shiny Dashboard Based on Inputs in UI

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinymodules

Let's say I have 4 sets of UI/Server modules in 4 different directories ("./X1/Y1/", "./X1/Y2/", "./X2/Y1/", "./X2/Y2/"). I want to load the selected set based on the input in the sidebar.

I tried using `source()` within `dashboardBody()`, but I was not successful.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# path to modules
in_path <- "C:/a/b/c/"

# ui
ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "test"),

  dashboardSidebar(

    br(),
    selectInput('f1', 'Folder 1', choices = c("X1", "X2")),
    helpText(""),
    selectInput('f2', 'Folder 2', choices = c("Y1", "Y2")),
    br(),
    actionButton("load", "Load", icon("thumbs-up"), width = "85%")

  ),

  dashboardBody(
    
    # UI module here from, e.g., "C:/a/b/c/X1/Y2/my_UI.R"
    
  )
)

# server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # server module here from, e.g., "C:/a/b/c/X1/Y2/my_Server.R"
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `shiny` modules are simply functions, I'd source them in the beginning, and use `uiOutput` to display the differnt modules.

Here's a working example of the general idea (sample module code proudly stolen from the official [Shiny documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)):

### `<mod1.R>`

```
counterButton <- function(id, label = "Counter") {
   ns <- NS(id)
   tagList(
      actionButton(ns("button"), label = label),
      verbatimTextOutput(ns("out"))
   )
}

counterServer <- function(id) {
   moduleServer(
      id,
      function(input, output, session) {
         count <- reactiveVal(0)
         observeEvent(input$button, {
            count(count() + 1)
         })
         output$out <- renderText({
            count()
         })
         count
      }
   )
}
```

### `<mod2.R>`

```r
csvFileUI <- function(id, label = "CSV file") {
   ns <- NS(id)
   
   tagList(
      fileInput(ns("file"), label),
      checkboxInput(ns("heading"), "Has heading"),
      selectInput(ns("quote"), "Quote", c(
         "None" = "",
         "Double quote" = "\"",
         "Single quote" = "'"
      ))
   )
}

csvFileServer <- function(id, stringsAsFactors  = TRUE) {
   moduleServer(
      id,
      ## Below is the module function
      function(input, output, session) {
         # The selected file, if any
         userFile <- reactive({
            # If no file is selected, don't do anything
            validate(need(input$file, message = FALSE))
            input$file
         })
         
         # The user's data, parsed into a data frame
         dataframe <- reactive({
            read.csv(userFile()$datapath,
                     header = input$heading,
                     quote = input$quote,
                     stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors)
         })
         
         # We can run observers in here if we want to
         observe({
            msg <- sprintf("File %s was uploaded", userFile()$name)
            cat(msg, "\n")
         })
         
         # Return the reactive that yields the data frame
         return(dataframe)
      }
   )    
}
```

### `<app.R>`

```r
library(shiny)

source("mod1.R")
source("mod2.R")

my_mods <- list("Counter Button" = list(ui = counterButton,
                                        server = counterServer),
                "CSV Uploader" = list(ui = csvFileUI ,
                                      server = csvFileServer))

ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         selectInput("mod_sel",
                     "Which Module should be loaded?",
                     names(my_mods))
      ),
      mainPanel(
         uiOutput("content"),
         verbatimTextOutput("out")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   uuid <- 1
   handler <- reactiveVal()
   
   output$content <- renderUI({
      my_mods[[req(input$mod_sel)]]$ui(paste0("mod", uuid))
   })
   
   observeEvent(input$mod_sel, {
      handler(my_mods[[req(input$mod_sel)]]$server(paste0("mod", uuid)))
      uuid <<- uuid + 1
   })
   
   output$out <- renderPrint(req(handler())())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Some Explanation

1. You put the module code in `mod[12].R` and it is rather straight forward.
2. In your main app, you load both(!) source files and for housekeeping reasons, I put both modules functions (`ui` and `server`) in a `list`, but this is not strictly necessary, but facilitates future extension.
3. In your `UI` you have an `uiOutput` which renders dynamically according to the selected module.
4. In your `server` you put the code to dynamically render the `UI` and call the respective server function.
5. The `uid` construct is basically there to force a fresh render, whenever you change the selection. Otherwise, you may see still some old values whenever you come back to a module which you have rendered already.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. I used uiOutput in ui. Then, in server, I used observeEvent and, inside that, I sourced the modules and used renderUI.